# Shell Script that checks the status of a list of services running on multiple machine and send an email as alert after checking the services

Tags: shell, unix

I want to make a shell script that firstly checks the status of services from list of services saved in a text file on multiple systems and then send an alert mail after execution ends.
like i have to take input from text files
1)Ip.txt="that holds ip of different systems"
2)Services.txt="that holds the list of services"

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
server_cnt=ip.txt;
serverip= 'cat $server_cnt;
servicename=service.txt;
servicelines= `cat $servicename;
email= 'cat $email.txt'
for i in $serverip
do 

for s in $servicelines 
do
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running"
    echo "$SERVICE is not running!" | mail -s "$SERVICE down" $email

fi
ctr1= `expr ctr1 + 1'
done
ctr2= `expr ctr2 + 1`
done
```

Comment: You wont find help here for such a question. We do not do your work. If you have trouble writing that script, then show us the code what you got and where you got stuck. Then we can together figure out what is wrong!

Comment: Instead of writing your own, looking into installing a monitoring service like Nagios

Answer (score 0):

Good news - there are already plenty of programs to do this!  See [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) for a popular one, but if you search around a bit you'll find plenty more.